# How do I create or import an Access database into a graph database

Tags: database, ms-access, graph-databases

The question is in the title really. I have seen some things about importing MySql or other telational databases into a graph database but I have a Microsoft Access 2003 database which cannot deal with complex queries so I want to export it into a graph database (including the data). Is this possible and if so then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention which graph database you want to export to, I am going to make a quick suggestion. I have used neo4j and it seemed very efficient. Also you can import data from mysql to neo4j by following [these guidelines](https://neo4j.com/blog/data-migration-between-mysql-and-neo4j/) provided on the neo4j site. You can import from csv or json as well. You can export data from MS Access in csv format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Graph Database you are using (AllegroGraph, ArangoDB, BlazeGraph, etc) however I do know Access has an export option. I know the 2010 version will export to XML. Try FILE|EXPORT :) If nothing else you can export to a delimited text. If you don't have Microsoft Access you're making your job very difficult. You could use some database connectivity and code a solution. There are a lot of connectivity tools available through Microsoft Studio using every language it supports (Visual Basic, C++, C#, etc).